# Kubernetes Network Policy - Allowing traffic to service over specific port only

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy, gke-networking

I have a GKE cluster v1.21 and have network policy enabled.

I denied all ingress and egress traffic within the cluster using:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-all-traffic
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

And I have a deployment and an internal load balancer the listens on 443:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: "Internal"
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-webserver
  ports:
    - port: 443
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And another deployment called my-deployment from which I want to send https requests to my-webserver.

**I've setup the following policies:**

Allow ingress for my-webserver

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-ingress-my-webserver
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-webserver
  ingress:
  - from:     
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-deployment
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Allow egress for my-deployment

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-my-deployment
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-webserver
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Those network policies don't allow me to send requests to my-webserver from my-deployment.

However, when **removing the ports section on both policies this works** - I can make https calls from my-deployment to my-webserver.

But, I want to be able to allow connections only on a specific port and a specific protocol.

Is there a way for me to restrict connections only to a specific port?

Answer (score 3):

You only have to open port 8080.
A Service in Kubernetes is something virtual and doesn't route or transfer traffic, the translation 443 -> 8080 happens locally on the Pod's node before the iptables rule is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are testing from a my-deployment's Pod and hitting the External LB's IP address, if that is the case; this is happening because the communication you are allowing is just from the source Pod to the service, you are missing the part from the service to the destination Pod.

As per Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/network-policy):

> You can use GKE's Network Policy Enforcement to control the
> communication between your cluster's Pods and Services. You define a
> network policy by using the [Kubernetes Network Policy API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to create
> Pod-level firewall rules. These firewall rules determine which Pods
> and Services can access one another inside your cluster.

What you need to do, is to allow the port 8080 as well in both policies:

```
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-ingress-my-webserver
spec:
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-webserver
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-deployment
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: allow-egress-my-deployment
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-deployment
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
  egress:
  - to:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: my-webserver
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 443
```

Comment: @Montoya, was this answer useful?